# How to separate variables in a bivariate polynomial

Tags: polynomials, algorithms

What is the general procedure for turning $P_1(x,y) = P_2(x,y)$ into $P_3(x) = P_4(y)$? I do not assume this is always possible, but for the cases it is possible, what is/are the general procedure(s) for rearranging an equation such that each side only contains one variable?

An example would be the following:

$$\begin{align} &xy = x^2 - \frac{xy}3 \\ \implies &\frac{4xy}3 = x^2 \\ \implies &\frac{4y}3 = x \end{align}$$

In the above example, I was able to improvise. With larger polynomials however, it gets harder and I wonder if it is impossible for some. So, what is/are the general procedure(s) for separating the variables in bivariate polynomials?